# Accessing the ControlsPlace Holders from Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, webforms

Hello I have been stuck with this situation for quite some time? Looking for some help here?

I have defined Nested Master Page (1 Default for WebApp and other Custom Master Page referencing the Default One)

The following is the code snipet from content page(say content.aspx) consuming my Custom Master Page

in aspx source code I have included:

```
%@ MasterType   VirtualPath="~/NestedMasterPage1.master" %>
```

and in code behind file ie. custom.aspx.cs (This is where the problem is):

```
ContentPlaceHolder masterContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Master.Master.FindControl("MainContent"); //works well
ContentPlaceHolder nestedContentPlaceHolderHeading = (ContentPlaceHolder)masterContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("NestedMasterHeading"); //works well
Label NewsHeadLines = (Label)nestedContentPlaceHolderHeading.FindControl("lblSubSectionHeader"); //returns null?? The Control ID is all checked and is the same in the Nested Master Page.
**NewsHeadLines.Text = "Testing";** //System.NullReferenceException:
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is it happening because I have nested my Control(here the label) in HTML Tables,rows and columns? Please advise? And I have double checked the control names or IDs.

Comment: Instead of using FindControl you should provide public properties in your master-pages that provide access to the appropriate controls' properties(f.e. `Text`). In this case you could implement a property `NewsHeadLines`. You always have a direct reference in the (master)pages to their controls. So you just need to cast your master to the correct type before you can access these properties.

Comment: Great Idea Tim. Missed that line of though. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be missing one or two nested containers. Try this; instead of you trying to figure out the nested containers try having a common programming logic to get them. Have a look at Rick Strahl's [blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Apr/09/ASPNET-20-MasterPages-and-FindControl)

Comment: Creating the <asp:Content /> Controls in the Source Code of my content page rendered the controls in my Nested Master Page to null.
hence forth All I had to do was to ***comment*** out the Auto Generated Source Code Snipet. 
Thanks for the reply and Thanks for the blog post link. I have been following quality blogs from authors including Rick Strahl's.